# Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm currently learning how to use CakePHP and I encountered a bug while testing the Delete function. Here's the error message:

> Error: Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object
>
> > File:C:\xampp\htdocs\Forum4Alliances\app\Controller\PostsController.php
> >
> > > Line: 57

Here's the code:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController{
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

 //Part is omitted...

public function delete($id){
        if($this->request->is('get')){
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if($this->Post->delete($id)){
            $this->Sessions->setFlash(__('The post with the id: %s has been deleted.', h($id)));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

As you see, I included the $helpers and $components. I couldn't find any answers past this point.

Cheers =)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's an user error: You've made a typo, it is singular, Session, not Session**s**.

Comment: I'm just curious, but why don't you catch that exception?

Comment: I'm strictly following the tutorial so that must be the reason. And thanks for your answer. Silly question of me.

Comment: @useruser3180037 C'mon no need to lie, I couldn't find a single "Sessions" on the whole page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts

Comment: @RPM Because this will trigger the correct HTTP error code. CakePHP offers a few exceptions that will do that, there is for example NotFoundException (404) as well that can be thrown and on purpose not catched to archive exactly this.

Comment: @burzum - so in production - don't catch exceptions?

Comment: @RPM No, I didn't say that. It depends on the kind of Exception and how you use it. You can catch the 404 as well if you like to. I usually throw it inside my Model::view($recordId) method when it could not find the record and don't catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined:

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

But than used:

```
$this->Sessions->setFlash(.. //**SessionS**
```

Correct to:

```
$this->Session->setFlash
```

Comment: Ok... Now I'm really ashamed of myself =(

I'm sorry to have post such a silly question and grateful for your nice and quick answer =)