# Error: Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object File: C:\wamp\www\CakePHP\app\Controller\PublishersController.php Line: 28

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php
class PublishersController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->set("publishers",
            $this->Publisher->find("all", array('order' => 'company_name ASC')));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $this->Publisher->id = $id;
        $this->set('publisher', $this->Publisher->read());
    }

    function edit($id = null)
    {
        $this->Publisher->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->data = $this->Publisher->findById($id);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->Publisher->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Publisher Updated Successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: Where you start sessions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034869/call-to-a-member-function-setflash-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you haven't loaded the Session class.

In either your AppController or your PublisherController you need to add the following:

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

That should fix it.